# Convert timestamp from API to date app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Running in App script, google sheet.
I get timestamp from API and return this result:

```
[[1.6370611672429312E18], [1.63706107263277082E18], [1.63706100204943616E18], [1.63706094340754534E18], [1.63706078474499994E18], [1.63706064715950106E18], [1.63706061367677235E18], [1.63706061367677082E18], [1.63706061367676902E18], [1.63706061367676749E18], [1.63706061367676595E18], [1.63706061367676442E18]],
```

Now I want to convert this timestamp to date to be like that: `10/28/2021 10:30`

I try this code: `var convertDate = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");` but not working any suggestoin

Comment: Not enough info here. What is the API? What is the code you're using to request the timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those timestamps are in nanoseconds, create a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) by dividing the timestamp value by a million.

```
const timestamps = [[1.6370611672429312E18], [1.63706107263277082E18]];
for (let i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
  const timestamp = new Date(timestamps[i][0] / 1000000);
  const convertDate = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro its work, I want to put this result to sheet by this code: `sheet.getRange(3,4,convertDate.length, convertDate[0].length).setValues(convertDate); // row && column` but give me this error: `Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.`. I use same this code to put another data in sheet and work fine.

Comment: @johnvan `setValues()` expects an array. Check out its documentation for an example.

Comment: in first I do `sheet.getRange(3,4,timestamps.length, timestamps[0].length).setValues(timestamps); // row && column`, this method add time stamp without any error in sheet, but after convert to Date give me this error. I think I need to convert `convertDate` to arrays like first return from API, How can I do that

Comment: @johnvan Please post a new question for that issue

Comment: you can see Bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989580/convert-timestamp-to-one-array